# How to to add static typing to variable in with statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2, python-typing

So I am working with psycopg2, and I create a cursor to execute some SQL script. Here is
the code for that:

```py
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    pass
```

I want to assign typing to the cursor variable from

```py
from psycopg2.extensions import cursor
```

But I cannot currently understand how to add typing to it.

Comment: Why? You will need to be more specific about what you mean by '...add typing to it'? My suspicion is that this can be done in a simpler manner.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want this for static type checking, you likely want to install the [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/stubs/psycopg2) package [types-psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/types-psycopg2/)

This will allow your type checker to use the external type stubs defined by the typeshed project, bypassing the need to manually annotate the types.